# taking a limit inside a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

dealing with the probability measure, I have that $$P(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = \lim_{M\to \infty}P(\cap_{n=1}^M A_n)$$ for some evens $A_n$. Could someone explain why we can do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is called continuity of measure from above. It applies for finite measures, including probability measures. Here is how to start the proof.

Write $P \left ( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right ) = P \left ( \left ( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c \right )^c \right ) = 1-P \left ( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c \right )$. Define $B_k=A_k^c \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{k-1} A_j^c$. The point of this step is that $\bigcup_{k=1}^n B_k = \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k^c$, but the $B_k$ are disjoint.

Then $1-P \left ( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c \right )=1-P \left ( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty B_k \right ) = 1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(B_k)$.

Can you finish the proof?

Comment: should be able to, thanks.

Comment: reference: http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/E_2.html